# How do I allow for all CSS while using HTMLPurifier to strip script tags?

Tags: php, htmlpurifier

Is there a way to have [HTMLPurifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/) allow for all CSS properties, so I can use it just to purify HTML concerns (e.g. script tags) and leave visual styling intact?

Comment: Do the settings CSS.AllowTricky / CSS.Trusted / CSS.Proprietary not do what you want? Can you share your current settings, your input, and your output? (The HTMLPurifier_AttrDef_Text solution seems like a very heavy-hitter, I have to admit I'm automatically concerned.)

Comment: Not as far as I could tell. The current settings are CSS.AllowTricky and CSS.Trusted set to true (lmk if you need the non-CSS ones too).

Comment: (Early return sorry about that) 
The simplest repro of one of the inputs causing me problems was like <div style="background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.5), rgba(255, 255, 0, 0.5))"></div>, and the current output was just <div></div> Other properties I had issues with were box-shadow, background-size, and another CSS 3 property that I'm forgetting at the moment (all of these were actually on just 2 example inputs, neither of which I have control over)

Comment: Ah! Yeah, it's almost surely the CSS3 stuff that's doing it - as awesome as HTML Purifier is, it is ancient. In theory you could create/overwrite the attributes you need in the same style as https://htmlpurifier.org/doxygen/html/CSSDefinition_8php_source.html, but whether the work you'd have to do it worth the security payoff is something only you can say. (In the project I used it in, it would definitely have been worth it.)

Comment: Yeah, it was a tough tradeoff, but there were too many (uncontrolled) inputs in my case to figure out what CSS to whitelist effectively and visual presentation couldn't be broken. Once other mitigation steps are in place though I might come back to this and see if I can't remove some of the riskier ones. 

And yeah ancient for sure, but I'm just thankful it exists and I don't have to do most of the hard sanitization work here myself...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if `$htmlPurifier` corresponds to your HTMLPurifier instance configured to use the default settings for CSS (i.e. passing none of the CSS configuration options), you can set the following before running the `purify` method

```
$htmlPurifier->config->getCssDefinition()->info = new class implements \ArrayAccess {
    public function offsetSet($offset, $value) 
    {
    }

    public function offsetExists($offset) {
        return true;
    }

    public function offsetUnset($offset) 
    {
    }

    public function offsetGet($offset) {
        return new \HTMLPurifier_AttrDef_Text();
    }
}
```

This will override the defaults set in [CSSDefinition.php](https://github.com/ezyang/htmlpurifier/blob/6f9aac9325e99a860928534cd4a5ade8962d3751/library/HTMLPurifier/CSSDefinition.php) and "trick" [this line in CSS.php](https://github.com/ezyang/htmlpurifier/blob/1354e7e8c558dc9ae353e07b8cde7ab0d46e7a25/library/HTMLPurifier/AttrDef/CSS.php#L83) into allowing any property through (using the HTMLPurifier_AttrDef_Text class appears to stop it from trying to do any further validation)